# How could I refactor this method in C#?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have code which I need to refactor in order to use in many places. So I tried some solutions but always ending with repeated and messy code. So, I decided to ask what is possible best solutions.

This code is used for calculating sale price in e-commerce project. My goal is to put some code in method which will not change over time, or better to say, which will be managed only from one place. This part is considering of setting sale price based on some comparasion.
And problem occurs in this comparasion. I want also to do some formating of controls like Label based on this result, like setting currency code. The currency code will be sometimes in  $, sometimes in USD. So, this mean I should somehow isolete this currency code also.

In short, I want to refactor this currency code and formating controls based on calculated sale price.

So, I created **BasketHelper** class with **Product** and **Account** properties and method  **SetBasketPayment** that return properties I setted in this method. Basically, I use this approach to group properties of **Product** and **Account** classes and than return values.

Here is my code. Any further explanation, I will provide upon your request.

```
public class BasketHelper
{
    public Product _product { get; set; }
    public Account _account { get; set; }


public BasketHelper SetBasketPayment(Product product, Account account, HyperLink lblIconOnSale, Label lblSalePrice, Label lblListPrice, HyperLink lblIconCampaign)
{
    decimal _brandAccountDiscountRate = default(decimal);
    decimal _accountDiscount = default(decimal);

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        MembershipUser mUser = Membership.GetUser();
        if (mUser != null)
        {
            account = Account.GetAccountByUserId((Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);
            try
            {
                _accountDiscount = account.DiscountRate;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }

            BrandAccountDiscount brandAccountDiscount = BrandAccountDiscount.GetBrandAccountDiscountByUserAndBrandId(product.BrandId, mUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
            if (brandAccountDiscount != null)
            {
                _brandAccountDiscountRate = brandAccountDiscount.DiscountRate;
            }
        }
    }

    decimal currencyMultiplier = Currency.GetCurrencyValue(product.CurrencyCode);
    decimal _listPriceTL = product.ListPrice * currencyMultiplier;


    decimal _productCampaignPrice = _listPriceTL * (1 - product.DiscountRate / 100);
    decimal _accountPrice = _listPriceTL * (1 - _accountDiscount / 100);
    decimal _brandPrice = _accountPrice * (1 - _brandAccountDiscountRate / 100);

    lblListPrice.Text = product.ListPrice.ToString("N2") + " " + product.CurrencyCode;

    if (product.DiscountRate > 0)
    {
        product.SalePrice = _productCampaignPrice;

        lblSalePrice.Text = _productCampaignPrice.ToString("C2") + " + KDV";
        lblListPrice.CssClass += " strike";
        lblIconCampaign.Text = "+%" + product.DiscountRate.ToString("N0");
        lblIconCampaign.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (_accountPrice < _listPriceTL)
        {
            product.SalePrice = _accountPrice;

            lblIconOnSale.Text = "%" + _accountDiscount.ToString();
            lblIconOnSale.Visible = true;
        }

        if (_brandAccountDiscountRate > 0)
        {
            product.SalePrice = _brandPrice;

            lblSalePrice.Text = _brandPrice.ToString("C2") + " +KDV";
        }
    }

    return new BasketHelper
    {
        _product = product,
        _account = account
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Code refactoring here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok. I will post my question there. I saw some questions related to refactoring on SO, but anyway I will post my question on codereview

Comment: The function is too long.  A function should do only one thing.  Also, add comments.

Comment: @pm_2. Thank you. I know that one method should be responsible only for doing one certain thing, but couldn't refactor it effectivelly.

Comment: Start by splitting it up.  It's very difficult to refactor a large method

Comment: @pm_2. I tried that. I put if else part in another method with parameters like accountDiscountRate, brandAccountDiscountRate and product but then I had to invoke this newly created method inside SetBasketPayment and for formating Labels also I had to invoke it in another place(Repeater). So, I didn't like that messy in my code.

Comment: Start by adding some comments. It will help others to understand it. Also, it will be easier for you to spot different responsibilities inside the method. After that you have to think how you want this responsibilities chained.

Comment: This belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @gleng. I posted it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46634/how-could-i-refactor-this-method-in-c